# Kineticist with several Energy Lashes

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

The Kineticist class from Expanded Psionics Handbook and Mind's Eye archive is, basically, a "trade your power progression for a number of specific energy power-like abilities at will". That is, subpar, but pretty flavory.

The first class level gives us the Energy Lash - a chosen energy ectoplasmic whip that is created at-will and is, for all the purposes, is treated as a whip (with touch energy attack instead of a normal physical attack) and dissipates the moment it leaves the user's hand - but what if the Kineticist wants to wield a whip in each of his hands?

So, the question is: Can a Kineticist create multiple whips as long as he still holds each in a hand (Like if he has 4 arms, for example)? If not, how about if he takes multiple different Kineticist classes (Like Pyrokinecist & Cryokineticist)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Fire Lash (Ps)**
>
> A pyrokineticist gains the ability to fashion a 15-foot-long whip of fire from unstable ectoplasm as a move-equivalent action. She takes no damage from a fire lash she creates, and if she releases her hold, it immediately dissipates. [...] The whip remains in existence as long as the pyrokineticist holds it.

The ability description mentions no limit to the amount of fire whips a creature can have other than them dissipating when let go off.

It's more ambiguous with Weapon Afire (which is quite important as a damage boost).

> **Weapon Afire (Ps)**
>
> At 4th level and higher, a pyrokineticist can activate this ability as a move-equivalent action. Flames that harm neither her nor the weapon engulf **one weapon she holds** (which can be a projectile such as a stone, bullet, arrow, or bolt). The weapon deals an extra 2d6 points of fire damage on a successful hit. The weapon retains this effect for as long as the pyrokineticist wields it.

Emphasis mine. The bolded part can refer either to

- The activation of the ability, meaning that you just get one weapon per move action
- The ability itself, meaning you only get to have it active on one weapon at any given time.

(Personally, I'd go with the first option.)

Note that creating multiple fire whips takes multiple move-equivalent actions. Double that if you use Weapon Afire. Then again, there's no time limit on the whips, so outside of ambush situations you should be fine.