# Can you have multiple enchanted Fire Lashes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, class-feature, psionics

Relating to [Can you enchant a fire lash?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124051/can-you-enchant-a-fire-lash):

Can you have multiple *fire lashes*, each enchanted differently (for example, +1 shock and +2 keen, choosing each time you summon a *fire lash* which type you want?

Comment: I disagree with those suggesting this needed to be a separate question. In fact, the suggestion to separate it seemed to be based in a misunderstanding of what was actually being asked. I don’t want to unilaterally dupe-close it, but I think it should be.

Comment: Related: [Kineticist with several energy lashes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44424/kineticist-with-several-energy-lashes?rq=1)

Comment: Or, perhaps, you should have waited to see how your other question was answered before asking this one: if the other question was answered in the affirmative, but didn’t address this, then this question makes sense. But since that question is answered in the negative (currently, but I doubt you’ll get an affirmative answer) this question makes little sense.

Comment: I changed my mind; I really do think this question isn’t helping anything. Considering @AVeryLargeBear agreed that the original suggestion to split was based on a misunderstanding, I think it’s better to just keep everything in the original question. Sorry for the run-around.

Comment: Should I delete this question?